# How to Change UITableViewCell's Height on Tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, delegates

I'm trying to have a UITableViewCell reveal more content about a particular cell whenever that specific cell is tapped. Once the cell has expanded and is tapped again, the cell should shrink back to its original size.

I'm pretty sure something has to be done with the delegates `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but I don't know how to select a specific table cell row using didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
// Height of table cell rows
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}

//On cell tap, expand
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 75;
}
```

Also, is it possible to hide any content that's overflowing from the parent cell? Kind of like overflow: hidden; in CSS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Declare a global variable **NSInteger** type and store **row** on tableview selected in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** and also reload here . After check row in **heightForRowAtIndexPath** and increase height there . 
Try Like this

```
var selectedIndex : NSInteger! = -1 //Delecre this global 

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == selectedIndex{
        selectedIndex = -1
    }else{
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedIndex
    {
        return 75
    }else{
        return 45
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't get any animation with this solution, unlike with Fayza's answer

Answer (score 9):

What you have to do is to save the index of the selected Cell in didSelectRow method. and also have to begin/end updates on table view. This will reload some part of tableview. and will call heightForRow method. In that method you can check that if your row is selected one then return expandedHeight, otherwise return the normal height

In height for row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if self.selectedSortingRow == indexPath.row {
        return ExpandedRowHeight
    }
    else{
        return normalHeight
    }
}
```

In didSelect Row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    selectedSortingRow = (int) indexPath.row        
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: let me know if you didn't get that

Comment: Got it, this and the other answer help a ton, thank you!

Comment: Note that you don't have to save your own variable for tracking this as the table view keeps track of its selected index path via `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`

Comment: I have done this and for some reason it doesnt animate it. It make it bigger, but doesn't perform any animation whasoever.

Comment: I'm doing this with a collectionView

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4 answer with recommended comments. No need to make a new variable, tableView holds a value for selectedRow indexPath.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row == indexPath.row {
        return 75;
    } else {
    return 45;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4. Animated resize with multiple selection. Based on Ryderpro answer.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        return 75
    } else {
        return 45
    }
}
```